# How to make custom options for any product in magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.4

One of my client want to have this kind of custom attributes in magneto, i tried making attributes and all, but can't get succeed, can anyone here guide me on making these ? do i have make attribute sets or attributes or i have to code custom ?

```
magento
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In default Magento you can have some thing like pic attached.. please view if this solve your problem ?[image]

Comment: Not actually, i have to make it as per my pic, because i have to take the prices dynamically. and all three should be only radio buttons.

Comment: In that case you should add dropdowns as mandatory and select boxes as not required.. after then using jQuery you can check that if standard stitching size is selected then the two dropdowns must be selected.. if you achieve this on adding product magento will itself tak all values selected correctly. hope this makes sense.